# Creating Verilog LZSS Pipelined Architecture from scratch

Tags: architecture, compression, verilog, register-transfer-level

I am designing an RTL in verilog for LZSS Algorithm. I have a working code of for this algorithm in verilog. This code is pretty much written in C++ style in verilog. It runs and all looks good.

Now I want to increase the speed of this algorithm and I want to pipeline it . I have a detailed flowchart of this algorithm. Now looking at this flowchart Can I decide How many pipeline stages will this end up in. IS there a limitation of how much combinational logic I can do in a stage.

Please help me lay down a step by step process to get this flowchart to a pipelined verilog code.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: copy of source code from http://collabedit.com/kvuu2

```
`timescale 1ns / 10 ps
`define EOF 32'HFFFF_FFFF
`define MEM_SIZE 200_000
`define NULL 0

//00 41 42 43 00 09 03 44 45 46 41 42 43

module UnCompBF ();

  reg [80*8:1] infilename;
  reg [80*8:1] outfilename;

  parameter EOF = -1;
  integer infile, outfile, mem_indx, file_char_rd;
  integer i, j, k, l;
  integer inc_i;
  reg[7:0] mem [4096:0]; // what size should i use??
  reg[7:0] out_mem [4096:0]; // what size should i use??
  reg[7:0]  get_char0, get_char1;
  reg[7:0] special_char;
  reg[15:0] length, offset;

  initial   
    begin :  uncompress_block
        //Load input binary file into memory
        infilename = "comp_out.bin";
        infile = $fopen(infilename,"r");
        //Check if input file is opened
    if (infile == `NULL)
        begin
        $display("Infile  -- file not opening");
        disable uncompress_block;
        end 

    i = $fread(mem[0], infile);
    $display("Loaded %0d entries \n", i); 
    $fclose(infile);

    //Open output file for writing
    outfilename = "out0.txt";
    outfile = $fopen(outfilename,"w");
    $display("input file loaded into mem and output file opened");

    //Initialize 
    mem_indx = 0;
    file_char_rd = 0; 
    special_char = 8'hxx;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;
    $display("initialize variables");

    //for (j=0;j<i;j=j+1)
  while (j<i)
    begin
            $display("In while loop -- j=%d -- i=%d", j, i);
            inc_i = 0;
            if (j == 0)
                begin
                    special_char = mem[j];
                    inc_i = inc_i + 1;
                    $display("first byte is marker j %d inc_i %d marker %h", j, inc_i, special_char);  
                    // else if not first char and current char is equal to value of special_char
                end 
            else if ((j != 0) && (mem[j] == special_char))
                begin
                    $display("byte is equal to marker");
                    //get next char
                    get_char0 = mem[j+1];
                    inc_i = inc_i + 2;
                    // if next char is equal to 00
                    if (get_char0[7:0] == 8'h00) // Marker is 0 hence unmatched literal
                        begin
                            // special character is actually unmatched char 
                            // write previous into output fie
                            $fdisplay(outfile, "%2h ", mem[j]);
                            // write previous into memory
                            out_mem[k] = mem[j];
                            k = k + 1;
                            $display("length is 00 meaning marker part of output");
                            $display("mem[j] %h -- k %d", mem[j], k);
                        end
                    else // get length and offset of match string // Otherwise move forward to get the lenght                                and offset
                        begin
                            // get length of match string
                            if(get_char0[7] == 1)
                                begin
                                    //get next char
                                    get_char1 = mem[j+2];
                                    inc_i = inc_i + 1;
                                    length = {1'b0,get_char0[6:0],get_char1[7:0]};  
                                end 
                            else
                                length = {8'h00,get_char0[7:0]};                                        

                                $display("length is %h -- inc_i %d", length, inc_i);    
                                // get offset of match string
                                get_char0 = mem[j+inc_i];
                                inc_i = inc_i + 1;
                            if(get_char0[7] == 1)
                                begin
                                    //get next char
                                    get_char1 = mem[j+inc_i];
                                    inc_i = inc_i + 1;
                                    offset = {1'b0,get_char0[6:0],get_char1[7:0]};      
                                end 
                            else
                                offset = {8'h00,get_char0[7:0]};                

                                $display("offset is %h -- inc_i %d", offset, inc_i);    
                        end
                            // write out the string match in file and memory    
                            for( l = 0; l < length; l = l + 1 )
                                begin
                                    out_mem[k] = out_mem[ k - offset ];
                                    // write previous into output fie
                                    $fdisplay(outfile, "%2h ",  out_mem[k]);
                                    $display("using the length/offset pair");
                                    $display("out_mem adds %h -- k %d", out_mem[k], k);
                                    k = k +  1;
                                end
                    // else write unmatched char into file and memory   
            end 

                else 
                    begin
                        // write previous into output fie
                        $fdisplay(outfile, "%2h ",  mem[j]);
                        // write previous into memory
                        out_mem[k] = mem[j];
                        inc_i = inc_i + 1;
                        $display("output unmatched char");
                        $display("out_mem adds %h -- k %d", out_mem[k], k);
                        k = k + 1;
                    end
          j = j + inc_i;
          $display("j is %d", j);
    end
    $fclose(outfile);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Can you add your current code? What is the target: ASIC or FPGA (which)? Longer combinational logic in every stage leads to lower target frequency of the circuit.

Comment: Hi osgx . Thanks for replying. Here is the code.

Comment: Sorry, but where "here" is code? And its flowchart, and your target (both FPGA name and target speed of data compression/decompression)

Comment: I am sorry, This is my forst post on stackoverflow ,so I was wondering. He re is a quick link http://collabedit.com/kvuu2

Comment: Also I want to do an ASIC. I can post the flowchart too if you like. The first commented line in the code that is // 41 41 43 .. is the input sequence to this program.

Comment: user, Sorry, I have no access to collabedit.com. Try to edit your post and add source here, or reupload it to other hosting. Post flowchart too. Will you do FPGA testing?

Comment: Your code can't be used for synthesis, it is not an RTL.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it appears the way you implemented this code is NOT synthesizable either to an ASIC or FPGA; the entire thing is just a single large initial block and uses various unsynthesizable system calls.

One thing that many people who have programming experience but are new to HDLs have trouble with is understanding the fundamental principles of designing HDL code vs software code. In software, you are giving a set of instructions to be executed in sequential order to be converted by the compiler into assembly instructions. In HDL code, you are providing a description of various hardware components to be converted by the synthesis tool into gates and very basic hardware components. When designing a piece of hardware, its best to try to construct the system as if you were drawing a circuit or RTL diagram (even doing it literally on paper can be helpful). Components can operate in parallel, take in inputs and drive outputs. You are not calling functions, you are instantiating modules (much closer to OOP, but still without the sequential element).

It would be best if you tried getting more practice with the basics before trying to implement something this complex. There are a number of tutorials online, but it might be better to study the basics of RTL design before diving into learning the language. Again, Verilog is an HDL, not a programming language, so don't just run into a tutorial as a way to learn the syntax. You need to approach it in a completely new way, starting from basic logic and RTL design on paper, then translating that design into HDL code.

The code above and your use of a flow chart indicate that you have a strong programming background, but in HDL, you need to be able to think in terms of an RTL or circuit diagram instead. Hope this helps and good luck with entering the world of hardware!